# Jquery Mobile: Applied background image to data-role="page" but now it leaves a gap beneath

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I've applied a background image to the div I use as my `data-role="page"` but now I realise it has also added a length to the div, below where the image ends. If I user scrolls down on the app, they see this gap.

Would anyone know how to fix this and have background images work properly with iOS devices?

My css is:

```css
#startuphero {
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url('../img/hero5.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML is:

```html
<body>
      <div id="startuphero" data-role="page" data-title="Home">

<!--INDEX MENU-->
        <div id="indexmenu">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="program.html" data-transition="slide"><img src="img/programicon.png"/></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="planner.html" data-transition="slide"><img src="img/plannericon.png"/></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="news.html" data-transition="slide"><img src="img/newsicon.png"/></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="word.html" data-transition="slide"><img src="img/wordicon.png"/></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="convo.html" data-transition="slide"><img src="img/convicon.png"/></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="designer.html" data-transition="slide"><img src="img/designicon.png"/></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
       </div><!--INDEX MENU-->         </div>
</body>
```

(PS: this is a PhoneGap/Cordova project on iOS)

Comment: Sorry, cant recreate your problem on iOS devices. Can you show us more of your HTML?

Comment: @Gajotres yep - added above